# Creating a mockup with photoshop using smart objects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, mockup

Hello everyone anyone who can take me through the process like placing a logo on a mug using smart objects. If anyone know a video tutorial please link me to it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site isn't really intended for providing full tutorials. It would be better if you do your own research, attempt to complete the task by yourself and then come here with specific questions if you find that you are stuck or unhappy with the results.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Chris' comment above: Please consider doing some research on your own before posting such a question. A quick google search will guide you to an abundance of tutorials and walkthroughs explaining exactly what you are looking for. Once you have started working on your design and you run into specific problems which you can't resolve on your own, come back here and post a question with a detailed outline of your specific problem so people here can actually help you.

Here are some resources for you to start with:

[Work with Smart Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html)

[Photoshop a logo on to a coffee mug using Adobe Photoshop 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9S2Rf84UgU)

[Photoshop Mug image wrap using replace content](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61762/photoshop-mug-image-wrap-using-replace-content)